# WPF Detect multiple HitTest on UIElement

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm doing a Spot The Difference game and I have bumped into a problem whereby I have seen users tried to use bot / autoclickers on to play it.

I'm implementing `Eclipse` geometry with click event to detect on the hit spot.

1) Is there a way for me to detect auto-clicker?

2) Is there a way to prevent multiple input at the same time? ( I may have worried they play on tablet and concurrently press on all the hit spot at the same time ).

I'm currently studying on the `VisualTreeHelper` which I see it might be helpful.

Is there any other alternatives that anyone can recommend me?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detecting spots and autoclicker may be tricky and not related to the technology itself (WPF, Eclipse ..) it's related on the game logic and the gamer's behaviour.

Take a look a this links :

[GameDevLink](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51150/how-can-auto-click-software-be-detected-to-stop-botting-cheating)

[WikiLink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheating_in_online_games#Anti-cheating_methods_and_limitations)

Comment: Hi @HichemCSharp , does that mean that we can't somehow validate the input from WPF side?

Comment: I'm not saying that, I meant that the logic behind validating an input in your case is a bit tricky.